# Will a mdl button or slider render identically for IOS and Android in Cordova?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova

I am developing an App with Cordova and Evothings. Buttons have a mld-button class in the EVOthings examples. `<button class="app-stop-scan mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--white mdl-button--disabled">`
Since mdl is an Android beast, will Cordova translate it into something IOS understands?
or should I keep away from platform-specific objects and use more generic HTML5, jQuery and javascript for buttons, sliders and other stuff?

Thanks